# Image name as string, use it to make image visible WPF with C#

Tags: c#, string, visibility

I have an image name as a string. The real imagename on the form is called "image". So i get something like this:

```
    image.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

string imageName = "image";
// need something here to make it usable...

changedImageName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Now, a string can not be used in combination with the Visibility property.
I cant really find what i must make the string to, to make it usable for the visibility property.
If i see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx
Do I understand correct that I make it a "enum" ? And if yes, how do I get a string to that property?

**EDIT 1**

I see I have not been explaining it proper enough.
I forgot to mention I am using a WPF form.
on this form, I have put an image.

In the initialize part, the image get set to hidden.
so for example the imagename I named "Image"
so I use         `image.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;`

later on in my code, I want to make the image visible again, depending on what the user does.
so, instead if just using the name to get the image visible again, I want to use a string.
this string is looking exactly as the name of the image.
but i cant use the string in combination with the Visibility function.
but i cant find anywhere what i must make this string to, to be able to use that visibility option on it.
hope i explained a bit better now :).

Later on, i will have multiple images on the WPF window.
So the key is that i will use the string, that is corresponding with the name of the image.
Depending on what the user has input into the string, some image will or will not show.

**EDIT 2**

If you have:

```
String theName = ImageName.name
```

you can get the name of the image into a string, so you can do stuff with it.
i am looking for a way to do the exact opposite of this. So i want to go from a string, to that name, so after that i can use this to control the image again.

**Edit 3**

some example:

```
        private void theButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //get the Name property of the button
            Button b = sender as Button;
            string s = b.Name;

            MessageBox.Show("this is the name of the clicked button: " + s);

            //the name of the image to unhide, is the exact same as the button, only with IM in front so:
            string IM = "IM";
            IM += s;

            MessageBox.Show("this string, is now indentical to the name of the image i want to unhide, so this string now looks like: " + IM );

            // now, this wont work, because i cant use a string for this, although the string value looks exactly like the image .name property
            // so string IM = IMtheButton
            // the image to unhide is named: IMtheButton.name
            IM.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: What kind of form? Silverlight?

Comment: To me your question makes no sense at all...

Comment: not really clear what you're asking for. What is relation between `name` and `Visibility` property.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm getting that he has a literal name of a control stored in a string variable and he wants to reference that control using the string so that he can set whether it's visible or not.

Comment: I assume you want to [parse a string to an enum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx). But your only string is `image` and not `Hidden/Visible`. So somewhat confusing.

Comment: @George I editted the title of the question, but now I think I understood it wrong way. Changing the name of the control at runtime doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: Is imageName the name of the image control or of the image file?

Comment: I am sorry i did not explain it good enough, have made an edit to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're using WPF, so you can create a **boolean to visibility converter** and use it with a boolean (and create a method that receives string if necessary) and just use:

```
<ContentControl Visibility="{Binding Path=IsControlVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"></ContentControl>
```

or any other converter...

check this links:
http://bembengarifin.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/setting-visibility-of-wpf-control-through-binding/

http://andu-goes-west.blogspot.com/2009/05/wpf-boolean-to-visibility-converter.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

EDIT 1:

so then you will have to iterate over the images and check if your string is equals to name of the Image class.

something like this (not tested):

```
foreach (Image img in container.Items)
{
    if img.Name == yourMagicallyString;
    {
        img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
else 
    {
        img.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: mm, no i dont really think this is what i was looking for. I have edited first post to explain more

Comment: i will see if this edit1 can work. also i edited my post some more (Edit 2 and 3)

Comment: yeah, and now you have to find the control with this name and change the visibility, to find the control: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/find-controls-by-name-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find a control based on the name or ID of the control. If so, try this:

```
Control changedImage = this.Controls.Find("image", false)[0];
```

Depending on what you are targeting and what version you might need to tweak a little

**EDIT** Updated per @Alexander Galkin comments about `Find` returning an array. There should definitely be some checking and whatnot but I'm leaving that up to the OP.

**EDIT 2** For [finding a control by name in WPF see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls).

Comment: He's using silverlight, whether he's mentioned it or not.

Comment: You should consider the situation that many controls can be found, `this.Controls.Find("image", false)[0]` will return the single control (or Exception if none is found). It is probably good to immediately cast it to `PictureBox` (this is how I understand the question) and to mention that this works in WinForms only.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Galkin, I forgot that it returned an array, answer updated.

Comment: i made some Edit to explain a bit more, sometimes its hard to describe situations haha

Answer (score 0):

The code I was looking for:

```
  object item = FindName(IM);
  Image test1 = (Image)item;
  test1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```